# Eureka based configuration server breaking actuator endpoints

Tags: spring-cloud

I setup my services to use the spring cloud eureka based config server.

version info: spring cloud 1.0.1.RELEASE

When I set it up as a fixed endpoint, I can see that it gets the right configuration file and that I can access actuator endpoints like health, info etc. so a .../manage/info returns the correct information.

However when I set it up to use discovery, the same actuator endpoints timeout on trying got access them.

In each case the configuration file is retrieved and downloaded (included log file).

Is there an issue with how I setup config server and bookmark service (the service which uses the config server)?

My configuration server setting is as follows:

```
server:
  port: 8888
  contextPath: /configurationservice

eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
  instance:
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 10
    statusPageUrlPath: /configurationservice/info
    homePageUrlPath: /configurationservice/
    healthCheckUrlPath: /configurationservice/health
    preferIpAddress: true

spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        native:
          searchLocations: file:/Users/larrymitchell/libertas/configserver/configfiles
```

The service bootstrap.yml settings are:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    default: development
    active: development
  application:
    name: bookmarkservice
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: true # note this needs to be turned on if you wnat the config server to work
#      uri: http://localhost:8888/configurationservice
      label: 1.0.0
      discovery:
        enabled: true
        serviceId: configurationservice
```

The application.yml settings are:

```
# general spring settings
spring:
  application:
    name: bookmarkservice
  profiles:
    default: development
    active: development    
# name of the service
service:
  name: bookmarkservice

# embedded web server settings
# some of these are specific to tomcat
server:
  port: 9001
  # the context path is the part after http:/localhost:8080
  contextPath: /bookmarkservice
  tomcat:
    basedir: target/tomcat
    uri-encoding: UTF-8

management:
  context-path: /manage
  security:
    enabled: false

eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
  instance:
    statusPageUrlPath: /bookmarkservice/manage/info
    homePageUrlPath: /bookmarkservice/manage
    healthCheckUrlPath: /bookmarkservice/manage/health
    preferIpAddress: true
```

The startup log for bookmark service is as follows:

```
2015-06-24 17:52:49.806 DEBUG 11234 --- [           main] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Created GET request for "http://10.132.1.56:8888/configurationservice/bookmarkservice/development/1.0.0"
2015-06-24 17:52:49.890 DEBUG 11234 --- [           main] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Setting request Accept header to [application/json, application/*+json]
2015-06-24 17:52:50.439 DEBUG 11234 --- [           main] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : GET request for "http://10.132.1.56:8888/configurationservice/bookmarkservice/development/1.0.0" resulted in 200 (OK)
2015-06-24 17:52:50.441 DEBUG 11234 --- [           main] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Reading [class org.springframework.cloud.config.environment.Environment] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@2b07e607]
2015-06-24 17:52:50.466  INFO 11234 --- [           main] b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration : Located property source: CompositePropertySource [name='configService', propertySources=[MapPropertySource [name='file:/Users/larrymitchell/libertas/configserver/configfiles/1.0.0/bookmarkservice-development.yml']]]
2015-06-24 17:52:50.503  INFO 11234 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5fa23965: startup date [Wed Jun 24 17:52:50 EDT 2015]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@5cced717
2015-06-24 17:52:51.723  WARN 11234 --- [           main] .i.s.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver : Skipping [/var/folders/kq/ykvl3t4n3l71p7s9ymywb4ym0000gn/T/spring-boot-libs/06f98804e83cf4a94380b46591b976b1d17c36b8-eureka-client-1.1.147.jar] because it does not denote a directory
2015-06-24 17:52:53.662  INFO 11234 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.config.PropertiesFactoryBean     : Loading properties file from URL [jar:file:/Users/larrymitchell/libertas/vipaas/applicationservices/bookmarkservice/target/bookmarkservice.jar!/lib/spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/META-INF/spring.integration.default.properties]
```

Comment: Do you have project that recreates the problem?  I'm unable to duplicate.

Comment: I am putting together one.  I am thinking it is some sort of library collision or something like that.  But I will put one together and put a diet up if I can get it to do it in a cut down version of my services

Comment: @spencergibb, I have created a sample project that has the problem.  I have stripped the service of all the extra stuff.  the project is at github at this location:  https://github.com/larry13767/configproblem

Comment: Using your project I was able to hit actuator endpoints in the bookmarkservice `http://localhost:9001/bookmarkservice/manage/env`.

Comment: I had a coworker try it and he got the same circumstance as I did.  It is conceivable that it is an environment and network issue.  I will try it at him on another computer.  Can you suggest any logs that I turn on to get greater detail?

Comment: `org.springframework.cloud`, `org.springframework.boot` and `com.netflix`, those are pretty broad.

Comment: I figured out what the issue is.  it is a matter of sequencing.  It is a bit long to describe so I will in the answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after talking it over with another coworker I figured out what the actual issue is.
Part of the confusion is that I am using the spring cloud (https://github.com/VanRoy/spring-cloud-dashboard) which is a great front end by the way.  So when the service starts we see it for to discovery and retrieve the correct configuration file and load it.  After I go to the spring cloud console and see a setting of UP which means that it is discovered and registered though discovery.  There is a second status indicator which is when the spring cloud dashboard takes the registered endpoint and get health. In my issue the endpoint was showing up as UNKNOWN.

If I then use the endpoint that shows up in the console and try the info actuator endpoint then the request times out.  This was the nature of my problem

Ok, so what was the issue?

Basically since I defined the  in the application.yml and since when the service registers in bootstrap it does not know the port yet and then it picks a default of 8080 (my assumption since that is what it does).  The server port is set in application.yml to 9001 but discovery sees a registration of 8080 so the spring cloud console cannot access the localhost:8080/bookmarkservice/manage/health since there is no service at that endpoint (which is at 9001 actually).  Other services also cannot find the service.

By moving the server.port to bootstrap.yml then the correct endpoint of rate service is registered and the service properly accessible.